# Is it possible to temporarily switch off tslint in visual code studio?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

I looked up this question, but I'm looking for a way to temporarily switch typescript linting off (not to uninstall everything). Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

find tslint in extensions, push small gear and disable it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in my case TSlint was not installed. I'll post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

When you click Extensions tab (control+shift+X) try find tslint in your "installed" list and click on "disable"

Comment: It was not tslint, i'll post a new question, thanks anyway!